# Using Semaphores to manage updating a global

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

I am working on a project where I have a thread that spawns threads based on a number input by the user.  I currently have the program working with one thread, where it finds the largest prime number in a 10 million integer array.  What I am trying to do is use a struct to assign each thread a block of the array but once I pass in more than one thread the subsequent threads never go.  The print statements are me data tracking

Currently if I input two threads the index only gets up to 500,000 here is the spawn thread function and the work function.  I cannot figure out why the other threads are not working.  i have the semaphores around the section where it updates the global variable to protect it.  The if statement in the creation thread is picking up the end of the array for odd number threads. It seems like it's creating the threads fine and sending them the right information.

I have been working on this day and night and really need to get the threads to work.  Thank in advance for any assistance. I cannot wait for the day when I am able to help people on here, I really want to thank the awesome community for being supportive and helpful on stackoverflow.

```
void* findPrime(void* pack_array)
{

  pack* currentPack =  pack_array;
  unsigned int lp = currentPack->largestPrime;
  unsigned int si = currentPack->startingIndex;
  unsigned int nc = currentPack->numberCount;

  int i;
  printf("Starting index Count: %d\n", si);
  for(i = si; i < nc; i++){
    if(i%100000==0)
      printf("Here is i: %d\n", i);
    if(entries[i]%2 != 0){
      if(entries[i] > currentPack->largestPrime){      
    if(prime(entries[i])){

      currentPack->largestPrime = entries[i];
      printf("%lu\n", currentPack->largestPrime);

    if(currentPack->largestPrime > largestPrimeNumber)
      sem_wait(&semHold);
      largestPrimeNumber = currentPack->largestPrime;
      sem_post(&semHold);
    }
      }    
    }
  }

}

void* assign(void* num)
{

  int y = (int)num;
  int i;

  int count = 10000000/y;
  int finalCount = count + (10000000%y);

  int sIndex = 0;
  printf("This is count: %d\n", count);
  printf("This is final count: %d", finalCount);


  pthread_t workers[y]; //thread to do the workers


  for(i = 0; i < y; i++){
    printf("for thread %d Starting index: %d\n", i, sIndex);
    if(i == (y-1)){
      pack_array[i].largestPrime = 0;
      pack_array[i].startingIndex = sIndex;
      pack_array[i].numberCount = finalCount;
    }

    pack_array[i].largestPrime = 0;
    pack_array[i].startingIndex = sIndex;
    pack_array[i].numberCount = count;


    pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, findPrime, (void *)&pack_array[i]);
    printf("thread created\n");
    sIndex += count;

  }
  for(i = 0; i < y; i++)
    pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);

}
```

Comment: It may help you to understand that semaphores are not decidedly ideal for data *protection*; they're ideal for *resource allocation*. Data protection is suited best by a mutex; data protection with change-notification is suited best by a condition-variable-mutex duo. Furthermore, this: `currentPack->largestPrime > largestPrimeNumber` is outside of any protection at all (that I can see, anyway). Isn't `largestPrimeNumber` a global potentially modified *and* evaluated by multiple threads? If so, both conditions need to be protected.

Comment: Is that the reason that my threads aren't even working? I put mutex locks around the sections you pointed out but the threads still don't report, there must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet the error is that you forgot to enclose the code at the if where you update largestPrimeNumber, and that is messing all up.

However, to protect the variable I would do the following instead:

Declare somewhere so it's global to the threads:

`pthread_mutex_t aMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;`

And substitute

```
if(currentPack->largestPrime > largestPrimeNumber)
  sem_wait(&semHold);
  largestPrimeNumber = currentPack->largestPrime;
  sem_post(&semHold);
```

for this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&aMutex);
if(currentPack->largestPrime > largestPrimeNumber)
  largestPrimeNumber = currentPack->largestPrime;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&aMutex);
```

Cheers